# HTML document shrinking after signing

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the Signable HTML method in DocuSign to create documents but when the signing process is complete the PDF shrinks which causes some tags to appear misplaced (not using any shrinking functions in the code) - images below for reference
[HTML doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAbuX.png)

[PDF end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2g1Xw.png)

Comment: As a workaround can you make the tags proportional to the container size, such as `max-height:100%` ?

Comment: how are you using the HTML? are you sure you are using Responsive Signing?

Comment: Using the method from this doc: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/creating-signable-html/

Comment: @Martin - tried the max-height method, unfortunately did not work

Comment: max-height can only work in some `display` or `position` CSS settings. Check that these are applicable on the given CSS

Comment: @Duke_Si1ver - Would you be comfortable posting the full HTML doc and envelope definition here? If not, you can reach out to DocuSign support privately by emailing go-live@docusign.com. If you do, please reference case number 06979341, and include your Demo/Production account IDs (if you have them). API Logs (https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) of the envelope creation call would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that when using HTML for signing you places the tabs (tags) inline in the HTML. [This code example](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/creating-signable-html/) shows how to do this. Here is how a tab element may look like in the HTML:

```
<input data-ds-type="number"/>
```